# return status from C finally and C2220

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, try-catch-finally

I i am using code as

```
NTSTATUS
Register (_In_ FLT_FILESYSTEM_TYPE VolumeFilesystemType)
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_FLT_DO_NOT_ATTACH;

    try {

        if (VolumeFilesystemType != FLT_FSTYPE_NTFS) {

            status = STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED;
            leave;
        }

        ...

    }
    finally {
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "AAFileFilter!Failed to register with status: %x\n", status));
            return STATUS_FLT_DO_NOT_ATTACH;
        }
        else
        {
            return  STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

I got [C2220](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksk5k0ta.aspx) for [warning C4532](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6b9te7b.aspx) . If i changing code as

```
...
    finally {
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "AAFileFilter!Failed to register with status: %x\n", status));
        }
    }

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) 
    {
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        return STATUS_FLT_DO_NOT_ATTACH;
    }
}
```

- Warning gone.. don't undestand what is the reason? The code should exactly works the same in both cases as for me. (I am using VS2013 with WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 project in C)

Comment: Huh? Surely this isn't C?

Comment: @unwind WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1 project it is only in c..

Comment: You didn't tell us what warning you're getting....

Comment: @BransDs Not really, the [`try-finally`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb3kz605.aspx) is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: @JohnZwinck i sad C2220. with link - warning treated as error - no object file generated

Comment: @BransDs: right, so "warning treated as error" tells us that the compiler treated your warning as an error.  Now what is the warning?

Comment: @JohnZwinck i updated post - 'continue' : jump out of __finally/finally block has undefined behavior during termination handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason why you are getting compiler errors is because this is not valid C.

- `try` does not exist in C (but in C++, Java, C#).
- `finally` does not exist in C (but in Java, C#).
- `leave;` is not valid C unless this is some macro you haven't posted.
- Functions returning a value, without containing a return statement are invalid in C, since 1999. And they are stupid, since the invention of C.

You might have to enable non-standard language extensions, or otherwise switch to a strictly conforming C compiler. Visual Studio is infamous for its poor standard compliance.

Comment: Those are extentions from MS.

Comment: This answer is not really relevant, yet was accepted.  Baffling.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well, the question is tagged C, so this is a C answer. Maybe there was some compiler option needed to make this nonsense language compile? My general advise is to use a C compiler for C, and a nonsense compiler for nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Exiting a try-finally statement using a return statement or the longjmp run-time function is considered abnormal termination. You probably get a warning about this and warnings are treated as errors.

PS. C support from Microsoft is crap.